# Add key to array of objects and persist the change using jq

Tags: jq

I am looping over array of s3 buckets in a json file.

```
[
  [
    "response": {
       "Buckets: : [
         {"Name": "foo"},
         {"Name": "bar"}
       ]
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to loop over each bucket, call the aws s3 api to get the region for each bucket and append the `{"region": "region_name"`} for each object inside `Buckets` array and persist the changes to file.

I am struggling to write the modified data to file as such that it doesn't lose all the data.

Below script writes to a `temp`.json file but it keeps overwriting the data for each run. In the end I only see last element in the `Bucket` array written to `temp.json` file

I want only the `region` key added to each element but keep all the contents of file same.

```
  jq -r '.[][0].response.Buckets[].Name' $REPORT/s3.json |
  while IFS= read -r bucket
  do
    region=$(aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket $bucket | jq -r '.LocationConstraint')
    jq -r --arg bucket "$bucket"  --arg region "$region" '.[][0].response.Buckets[] | select(.Name==$bucket) | .region=$region' $REPORT/s3.json | sponge $REPORT/temp.json
  done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the context by adding parentheses to the LHS as in `(.[][0].response.Buckets[] | select(.Name==$bucket)).region=$region`.

```bash
jq -r '.[][0].response.Buckets[].Name' $REPORT/s3.json |
while IFS= read -r bucket
do
  region=$(aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket $bucket | jq -r '.LocationConstraint')
  jq -r --arg bucket "$bucket" --arg region "$region" '(.[][0].response.Buckets[] | select(.Name==$bucket)).region=$region' $REPORT/s3.json | sponge $REPORT/temp.json
done
```

---

With a little bit more refactoring, you could also immediately provide the bucket name to the first inner `jq` call, which can already create the final objects, which can then be fed as an array to the outer `jq` call using `--slurpfile`, for instance. This would move the second inner `jq` call outside the loop, reducing the overall number of calls by one order.

```bash
jq --slurpfile buckets <(
  jq -r '.[][0].response.Buckets[].Name' $REPORT/s3.json |
  while IFS= read -r bucket; do
    aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket $bucket | jq --arg bucket "$bucket" '{Name: $bucket, region: .LocationConstraint}'
  done
) '.[][0].response.Buckets = $buckets' $REPORT/s3.json | sponge $REPORT/temp.json
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! I am still trying to understand the solution. But it unblocked me. Thank you so much !